# Replacing a damaged OCI card in India

Tags: india

I am a US passport holder, currently visiting India with an OCI card. I spilled water, and the OCI card is badly damaged. What would be the procedure to replace just the OCI card while in India?

From what I see I need to use https://ociservices.gov.in/welcome and go through the Miscellaneous services tab. But it is not clear to me what, if any supporting documentation is needed. A police report is not relevant since I still have the (damaged) OCI card. I think these are needed

- Current US passport
- A passport photograph

What other documents are needed, and, typically, how long does it take. Where do I send the documents? I have to travel back in about a month.